# Civicrm Integration: Error while adding api function

Tags: api, extension, civicrm.settings.php

I have CiviCRM 4.7 installed on drupal 7.38. I Found it necessary to modify the url in civicrm.settings.php file as suggested here:
https://forum.civicrm.org/index.php?topic=33303.0
After this modification, my extension was successfully created and I enabled it. Also I have added a page and can already pull some data from the database using the CiviCRM api and display it on the page I added. I now intend to add an api function for an already existing entity, FinancialItem.
When I run the command(in the terminal):

> civix generate:api FinancialItem Create

I get the following error[image]

Any suggestions as to what I should do to fix this?

Comment: Suggestion 1: You shouldn't need to `sudo` to run `civix`. My advice to those who often run sudo is: *stop*, *understand* and *address* the underlying permissions problem, rather than whacking it with a "sudo hammer". Reflexive sudo-ing is a habit worth kicking.

Comment: Suggestion 2: Drupal 7.38 is harmless enough for developing locally, but if you'll be using the same codebase on the internet, you should ensure you're running a recent copy of Drupal with all available security updates applied.

Answer (score 1):

This looks like your CiviCRM install has an extension enabled in the DB which is not present, or was moved, on your disk.

Perhaps the extension you're working on was renamed after first being enabled, perhaps other changes were made to info.xml or the core extension files, perhaps it was moved, or perhaps your DB had another extension enabled on the remote server which isn't present locally.

The CiviCRM extensions page might be informative to check, otherwise you can compare extensions listed in the database to the ones which are available locally.

Answer (score 0):

From the image you are using an extension that has an API with the name FinancialItem and You are trying to add an API that already exists in the extension with the same name in the extension cm.mukwetest.firstextension.

I don't think that is possible.

You the github repo is found here https://github.com/mercimukwe/cm.mukwetest.firstextension to see the content whole extension and the APIs which have been added.